# How to calculate $lcm(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$ solely by mental arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Denote $lcm(a,b)$ the lowest common multiple of $a$ and $b.$

> Question: How to calculate 
>   $$lcm(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$$
>   solely by mental arithmetic?

I have a way to calculate, but it relies on writing on paper. 
We can calculate the lcm using recursively, that is, 
$$l = lcm( lcm(2,3),4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ) = lcm(lcm(6,4),5,6,7,8,9,10) = lcm(lcm(12,5),6,7,8,9,10)...$$
I know that my notations above are not correct but hopefully the idea can get through.

Comment: That's how I would do it mentally too. After all you only need to think about two numbers at a time.

Comment: It is also useful to have a code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777358/how-to-calculate-the-least-common-multiple-of-the-numbers-1-to-10), because $\operatorname{lcm}(1,\ldots ,100)$ might be your next homework.

Comment: What is "mental arithmetic"? Btw, I would pick out the largest $p$-powers for primes $p$ and multiplicate: $2^33^25^17^1$.

Answer (score 9):

Since we have a list of consecutive integers starting from $2$, just pick  the largest powers of a prime:
$$\text{lcm}(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)=\text{lcm}(5,7,8,9)=5\cdot 7\cdot 8 \cdot 9=63\cdot 40=2520.$$

Comment: And now please "mentally" $5\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9=2520$ :)

Comment: $5\cdot8\cdot7\cdot9=40\cdot63=10\cdot2\cdot2\cdot63=10\cdot2\cdot126=2520$